# How to generate pdf file from dynamic data coming from mysql database in php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, pdf-generation

I am doing one web application society management system. In this application I want to generate pdf file for each user separately. Means during invoice generation , if there are 10 users then for each user separate invoice should get generated as a pdf after clicking on generate PDF button. My invoice got generated for each user but now I dont understand how to convert it into pdf dynamically. So please help me in this question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use any of the following php scripts to generate dynamic PDF documents

fpdf: http://www.fpdf.org/

tcpdf: http://www.tcpdf.org/

Answer (score 4):

You probably have to check out this lib: [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)

It's quite easy to use and allows you to generate PDF from HTML templates.