# How to get data from the database and show them in a custom pdf file

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf

I want to get data from my database and these data I want to show them to the user by giving him a pdf file.
For example I will get the name, email of the user from the database and then I want to print
on the screen that data in a pdf file.
Is there any way to do that?

PS: I am using php, html and mysql

Comment: Write a pdf by php? Sure, Show data from db to html? Sure, Create a pdf from Php? Sure, simple google http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349873/how-to-generate-pdf-file-from-dynamic-data-coming-from-mysql-database-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favorite PHP PDF creator is MPDF http://www.mpdf1.com/
Just echo out your data into table like you would in html but it must be echoed into a string.
then mpdf will convert the sting html into a pdf.